# Generic Interface, IEnumerable

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

I Have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QQQ.Mappings
{
    interface IExcess<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<string, T> getExcessByMaterialGroup(T[] data);
        void Sort<TKey>(T[] data, Func<T, TKey> selector);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error, *"Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' requires '1' type arguments"*

Comment: 7 answers, and they are all more or less identical; I'd say you got your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to return `IEnumerable<string, T>` from getExcessByMaterialGroup. `IEnumerable<T>` only takes one type parameter, not two (String and T).  My guess is that you want to return something like `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, T>>`

Comment: Right, I was looking for IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, T>>

Answer (score 7):

There is no standard `IEnumerable<T, K>` generic type interface, only `IEnumerable<T>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)). 
I believe you are need `IDictionary<string, T>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx)) instead

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` is the only method there is no `IEnumerable<T,T>` but you can use `IDictionary<T,T>`

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem, IEnumerable has only 1 generic argument.

```
IEnumerable<string, T>
```

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable only accepts a single type argument. You should be declaring that as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable only has one type argument, yet you have specified two (string, T). You probably want something like:

```
IEnumerable<string> getExcessByMaterialGroup(T[] data);
```

if the method is supposed to return an enumerable of strings.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` exists, there is no dual dictionary style `IEnumerable<T, U>`.

If you're looking for a KeyValue like relationship, consider `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>`